# Experimental evidences satisfying charged particle emits radiation in gravitational field

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, radiation, maxwell-equations, equivalence-principle

Is there any experimental evidence exist that a charged particle at rest in gravitational field emit radiation and charged particle in free fall don't emit radiation  ( According to equivalence principle )?

Comment: Charged particle in a static gravitational field that is held at rest (relative to a static frame) by external forces would not be emitting any radiation. Conversely, freely moving charged particle in a gravitational field would emit radiation. So no, there are no experimental evidence for nonexisting effects.

Comment: see my answer here , https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/258019/can-the-question-of-a-gravitationally-accelerated-charge-radiation-be-tested-exp/258027?noredirect=1#comment994048_258027 . imo the effect predicted mathematically cannot be measured because of the  very small value of the gravitational constant, certainly  no experiment.