# Experiment of an accelerated charge’s radiation in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, charge, acceleration

I have seen a video saying a stationary (from our frame) charge should radiate, because is accelerated, the falling charges are the ones with no acceleration.
But he says we cannot test it due some technical challenges, what are those challenges?

// Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRr1kaXKBsU

Comment: it's duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/258019/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the question of a gravitationally accelerated charge radiation be tested experimentally?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/258019/)