# If an electron is a singularity do we talk about a black hole?

Tags: electromagnetism, black-holes, electrons, event-horizon, elementary-particles

As the standard model states an electron is a pointlike particle. If it is really so it has all features to be thought of as a mini black hole but then there is the problem how a such black hole can emit EM waves.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are electrons just incompletely evaporated black holes?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/75911/)

Comment: In the classical view, the electron also is an electromagnetic singularity, but this is resolved by Quantum Mechanics. Similarly, you cannot apply classical General Relativity to quantum objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classical black hole as small as an electron would evaporate due to [Hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation) in a time much shorter than the [Planck time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_time). We know this is absurd. Therefore electrons cannot behave like classical black holes. It is also doubtful whether they are really pointlike particles. In the two leading candidates for a theory of quantum gravity - [string theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory) and [loop quantum gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_quantum_gravity) - there is no such thing as a pointlike particle.

Comment: Your arguments are speculations. The Hawking radiation does not exist in GR, because it violates the main postulate of relativity. It is but an unobserved artifact of trying to mix GR with QFT without knowing how they actually work together. Secondly, electrons are point-like particles in the accepted Standard Model. String Theory and Quantum Loop Gravity are speculations, not validated theories.

Comment: In my experience, only a tiny percentage of physicists think that Hawking was mistaken about Hawking radiation. There are a variety of arguments that all lead to the same conclusion he reached.

Comment: @G.Smith Indeed, but still, the semi-classical gravity is not a theoretically strict or experimentally validated theory plus it violates the main postulate of GR, which is a validated theory. So there is no presumption of innocence for Hawking - his radiation doesn't exist, unless experimentally observed. Having said this, I agree that the root cause is much deeper. For example, charges radiating or not in gravity depending on the frame also violate the principle that physics does not depend on our viewpoint. So our understanding of how gravity and electromagnetism work together is incomplete.

Comment: @G.Smith There is a good related discussion here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/390230/

Comment: @safesphere And here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21830 Pay more attention to schirmer and AVS than bobrick.

Comment: A classical GR solution with the mass, charge, and spin of an electron would be a naked singularity without an event horizon, and therefore without Hawking radiation.