# Accelerating charge in different frames

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-electrodynamics

We know that accelerated charges radiate energy in form of electromagnetic radiations. Since acceleration is frame dependent, is the radiated energy also frame dependent? Is that why energy radiated is different in different frames?

Answer (score 1):

Acceleration is the *same* in all inertial reference frames, so all inertial observers agree on the energy radiated by an accelerating charge.

Comment: but what if we are in non inertial frame

Comment: That’s complicated. Here is a related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21830/does-a-charged-particle-accelerating-in-a-gravitational-field-radiate