# Does an accelerated electron (due to gravitation) emitts e.m. radiation?

Tags: general-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, acceleration, equivalence-principle

Due to Einstein's equivalence principle, I think this is not the case. In the Liénard–Wiechert potential (which describes the em radiation of accelerated charge) I do not see the source for the acceleration - but it has to be there since otherwise, it would be independent of the source (gravitational source or electric/magnetic field).

So, my question is - where in the Liénard–Wiechert potential is the source for the acceleration, and would another source (gravitation) cause the same effect?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21830/123208 & the links therein.