Does a charged particle under constant acceleration produce electromagnetic waves?
A charged particle at rest does not emit any electromagnetic waves. It is generally said that an accelerated charged particle does produce electromagnetic waves. But according to Einstein's Principle of Equivalence from General Theory of Relativity, there is no difference between the Earth frame and a non-inertial accelerated frame with acceleration = gravitational acceleration. A charge at rest does not emit electromagnetic waves. Does that mean a charge under acceleration also does not emit electromagnetic waves (at least at acceleration= 9.8 m/s^2)
Or is it that an accelerated charge produce electromagnetic waves and that also means that a charge at rest on earth frame also emit waves.
Which is correct?

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox_of_radiation_of_charged_particles_in_a_gravitational_field

Does this answer your question? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21830/180843
